# condition in tag xhtml with JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, if-statement, primefaces

I have this part of code using primeface component :

```
<h:outputText value="Division : " />  
                        <p:inplace id="basic2">  
                            <p:inputText value="#{utilisateursController.u1.division}" />  
                        </p:inplace>
```

I want to testing if #{utilisateursController.u1.division} is equals "" (or null) it displays "Please enter a valid division" otherwise, it displays the value of #{utilisateursController.u1.division}

I have already see that somewhere but I don't know how to use

can you remember me ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
<p:inputText value="#{(not empty utilisateursController.u1.division)?utilisateursController.u1.division:'Please enter a valid division'}" />
```